# Numeric data-type for integers

Tags: postgresql, datatypes

I need to store exact sums of `bigint` columns in a summary table. So I must use data type `numeric` for those columns.

Now I am wondering if setting the scale to `0` in this case makes sense (e.g. maybe some performance benefit?)

If so, then how can I set the scale to `0` and still keep the default precision:

- according to the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-TABLE) the data-type `numeric()` (without explicit precision and scale) supports:

  > **up to `131072` digits before the decimal point**;up to 16383 digits after the decimal point
- But when we explicitly set the precision and scale, the max. allowed value for precision is only `1000`: i.e. `1000` digits before the decimal point, right?

  > The **maximum allowed precision** when explicitly specified in the type declaration **is 1000**;

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is true (and a bit surprising).

You need to add quite a lot of `bigint` values to exceed `numeric(1000,0)`, so I think you should be safe with that.

Comment: That's true, but on the other hand, when setting the scale to `0` has not real benefit, I'd rather use the default `numeric()` - just to be safer :)

Comment: Sure, that's no problem.